# auto logoff from all apps on android

Tags: security

i want a functionality where i can log off from all the apps on android ie: auto logoff from skype , facebook , yahoo.

Is a some app already available for this or some easy way to implement this. I tried clearing all the cache but does not log out the app.

their is a app called social secure for ios but nothing for android

Comment: Android is designed to not let apps interact with other apps in an attempt to provide a more secure platform. It might be possible on a rooted device, but I have never seen an app that would do that. The logistics would be crazy, because the developer would have to program each and every different app that should be logged out into the app. And any time one of those apps are updated, it could possibly break the logout app. I don't think you will see anything like this on Android.

Comment: Thanks , after check i saw that even if i am able to clear all the data and cache then the app is logged out. is their any app that has the functionality to clear all the data of selected apps. i think its built in 4.2 but not in 4.0.2 (i cannot upgrade)

Comment: You can wipe any application's data from within Settings -> Apps -> app_name -> Wipe Data (names might be slightly off since I haven't run ICS for awhile). Titanium Backup can do it, but I can't see any way to automate it, only wiping the apps individually. I don't know of any apps that can automate wiping the data for a selected number of apps while leaving everything else untouched.